# ANTLR4 repeating ANDs

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, antlr4, expr

With the following rule:

```
expr:
 '(' expr ')'  #exprExpr
|   expr ( AND expr )+  #exprAnd
|  expr ( OR expr )+  #exprOr
|  atom #exprAtom
|  ID  #exprId
;

atom:
  '[' ID RELOP INT ']'
;
```

I would like to allow statements like this:

```
[a<3] and [b<4]
[a<3] or [b<4]
[a<3] or ([b<4]and [c<5])
```

but forbid statements like this:

```
[a<3] or [b<4] and [c<5]
```

This basic idea  seems to work with this grammar.
But there is one aspect/side effect, which I do not understand:

While parsing code with 3 atoms ( like atom1 and atom2 and atom3)
the method exprAnd ist called twice (not once, as I would expect
it to).

So code like this:

```
 public String visitExprAnd(myParser.ExprAndContext ctx)  {
String res = "";
int type=-1;

int nAtoms = ctx.atom().size();
for (int i=0;i<nAtoms;i++) { 
  String s = visit(ctx.expr(i));
}
return s;

}
```

does not work for all and-expressions at once.

So somehow I would have expected the exprAnd and exprOr rules to be 
more greedy.

How could one achieve this?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your grammar still accepts `[a<3] or [b<4] and [c<5]`, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

> but forbid statements like this:
>
> ```
> [a<3] or [b<4] and [c<5]
> ```

That is best done after parsing. Your grammar accepts this (and it should). You just need to walk the parse tree afterwards and reject it when you encounter it during a tree-traversal.

> While parsing code with 3 atoms ( like atom1 and atom2 and atom3) the method exprAnd ist called twice (not once, as I would expect it to).

If you want to group these `AND`s together, you should do something like this instead of grouping it all together in a single `expr` rule:

```antlr
orExpr
 : andExpr ( OR andExpr )*
 ;

andExpr
 : atom ( AND atom )*
 ;

atom
 : '(' expr ')'         #atomExpr
 | '[' ID RELOP INT ']' #atomBracket
 | ID                   #atomId
 ;
```

### EDIT

A complete example:

```antlr
grammar Test;

parse
 : expr EOF
 ;

expr
 : orExpr
 ;

orExpr
 : andExpr ( OR andExpr )*
 ;

andExpr
 : atom ( AND atom )*
 ;

atom
 : '(' expr ')'            #atomExpr
 | '[' expr RELOP expr ']' #atomBracket
 | ID                      #atomId
 | INT                     #atomInt
 ;

RELOP : [<>] '='?;
AND   : 'and';
OR    : 'or';
INT   : [0-9]+;
ID    : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]*;
SPACE : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Comment: I tried the seperate orExpr and andExpr rules.
It seems to have a problem with statements with 
parenthesis like this:    [12<34] and ([5<6] or [7<8]);
Error is: "extraneous input '(' expecting '['"

Comment: I tried this to include the paranthesis rule:

  andExpr: 
    bid ( AND bid )*
   | '(' expr ')'
   ;

but this also gives an error (-> "expecting '[')

Comment: Well, `[12<34]` doesn't work because in your original grammar you defined it as such: `'[' ID RELOP INT ']'`. What you need to do is something like this: `'[' INT RELOP INT ']'` or even: `'[' expr RELOP expr ']'`. Also check my **EDIT**.

Comment: Sorry, my post was slightly misleading. I did simplify the grammar. Originally it waw  like this:
Ident:  INT | ID;
and

Comment: atom : ...
| '[' Ident RELOP INT ']'

Comment: I still am testing. My version with your modified code still has the same error. Starting with your grammer code the parenthesis is processed correctly, I still dont understand, why my grammar has this error and yours not. But I will try to figure out and comment on this point if I find the difference. Thanks for your help!